# href not working in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application, I have a controller `hiring` and in the `view` tree `hiring` controller have one page `new` and I add another page called `viewhiring` also
and I have added two tabs in both `hiring` and `new` page i.e below:

```
<div id="nave">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="sub"><a href="/hiring/viewhiring">View Hiring</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="<%= templates_path %>">Hiring</a> //new page that I call hiring
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I want  to redirect from `Hiring` page to 'View Hiring' page using anchor `<a href="/hiring/viewhiring">View Hiring</a>` but its not working.
kindly help me, waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Comment: What does "not working mean"? We can't possibly help you with so little description of the problem.

Comment: means not going from `Hiring` page to `View Hiring` page, and how to I set path in `href`.

Comment: Try using the correct format for a link - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to 

Don't use <a href="">

Answer (score 4):

[**Helpers**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)

You should read up about [Rails URL helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) - you shouldn't be using `<a href="">` in your view files, you can use `<% link_to %>` instead (as pointed out by `@deepti Kakade`):

```
<%= link_to "Hiring", templates_path %>
```

You really need to use all the `rails` helpers (there are many more than just `link_to`) in place of your HTML because they firstly help you keep your code DRY, but secondly ensure you're keeping up with the latest Rails developments

One of the main benefits of using a framework such as Rails is that it gives you the ability to focus on creating an amazing system, rather than worrying about small coding complications

--

**Routes**

Secondly, you have to consider your [`routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :hiring #-> hiring_path / domain.com/hiring/index
```

Rails' routing uses a [`resourceful`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) structure - meaning it allows you to build a set of routes *around* "resources" in your application. Simply, "resources" are your controllers; but they're really your individual data records:

[image]

In this sense, you should look at which `path` you're using, as it will correspond directly to your `routes`

Answer (score 3):

Use link_to, it generates the anchor tag of html, for example

```
<%= link_to "linktext", action_path %>
```

your action_path is nothing but the href.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div id="nave">
  <ul id="menu">
   <li class="sub"> <%= link_to 'View Hiring', hiring_viewhiring_path %></li>
   <li class="sub"><%= link_to 'Hiring', templates_path %></li> //new page that I call hiring
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it helps .

```
'View Hiring'= is the name posted .

hiring_viewhiring_path = is the path
```

eg. welcome_index_path

```
 this path is in \app/views/welcome/index.html
```

Did you get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
  # url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
  # posts_path
```